# Re-entering Schengen from UK 90/180 day rule for American tourist

Tags: schengen

I have been studying in the UK for over a year but my student visa expired (I'm American) at the end of January 2019.  But, I entered the Schengen Zone on 5 July 2018, I was in and out until 11 November and had accumulated 22 days total. I have not gone back into the Schengen Zone/Area since 11 November (I went to Romania for 4 nights around New Years but they're still not part of the Schengen Area). I plan to go to Denmark in mid March 2019 from the UK, but I'm not sure if I can enter the Schengen Zone still?  I have been getting various answers and I am very confused if I can get in still or not? 
This is not for a Schengen Visa, I am mearly trying to re-enter the Schengen as a tourist.  The question would be:
After the 180 days, do I have to wait another 90 days to re-start the 90/180 rule or does it start automatically after the 180 days have been up (which would of been 5 January). This is as an American tourist, not a Schengen Visa holder. None of the other questions have really addressed this even though it has been marked as a duplicate.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain what part you are confused about specifically? The question I've linked includes a calculator which might make it easier to work out.

Comment: Read the answers on that linked question. There is no magic 90 days. The period rolls.

Comment: i think it's because they're all talking about going in with Visas and then having to re-apply for a visa.  Not really sure if this pertains to me as I don't need a Visa with an American passport. So if I haven't been in the Schengen in the last 90 days I should be fine to go to Denmark then? That's all I want to know.

Comment: @Tony The rules apply to visa holders and to visa free nationals like you, just the same. There is a rolling window. For every day that you are in Schengen, you must not have been in Schengen for more than 90 of the previous 180 days. If you haven't been in Schengen in the last 90 days then this is *likely* to be true. Use the calculator linked to in the other question if you are unsure.